# Migrate Sharpoint site to Google site

Tags: sharepoint, google-apps-script, google-apps

Is there any tool or service provided by Google by which i can completely migrate my sharepoint site to google site ?

If it is not possible, then can i move folders directory from sharepoint to google drive ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the open with Explorer option to do this manually https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2629108. Or sync the library first, and copy the documents.